# Passing Variable in SSIS

Tags: sql-server, ssis

I need some help to pass row value to the other task in SSIS package. Here is my sample query select distinct txnno from tbltxn, what I need is to get distinct txnno from this query and delete records from other table based on this txnno. I think we can pick txxno in some variable in a foreach in a container and pass that recordset value to the query which is used to delete.But I have not done this before, so I need some clues and examples to solve this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Here you go - the documentation includes a link to samples on Codeplex:

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc280492.aspx